# Suddenly after Heroku deployment I get ClassNotFoundException: scala.App

Tags: scala, heroku

I did not change anything in the Build.sbt or in the app, still my app does not run on Heroku anymore saying

Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djava.rmi.server.useCodebaseOnly=true 
Aug 19 06:37:15 moments-production app/web.1:  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/App

Anybody an idea? I am trying to fix this for hours now, driving me crazy

Comment: Maybe it doesn't solve your issue but it's worth a try, have you set SBT_clean to true? `heroku config:set SBT_CLEAN=true`, you need to redeploy after.

Comment: Yes I already tried that, but thanks!

Comment: It started with some issues with the new relic path -javaagent:./.sbt_home/.ivy2/cache/com.newrelic.agent.java/newrelic-agent/jars/newrelic-agent-3.1.1.jar . Then removed new relic from the app. I am gonna add the new relic stuff back now to see what the original issue was and maybe fixing that fixes the whole shit pile.

Comment: scala/App is not present in older scala versions, can you ensure that scala versions are fresh and match each other?

Comment: I did not change the scala versions. I am using 2.10.3. So I added back new relic and get the original error now app/web.1:  Error opening zip file or JAR manifest missing : ./.sbt_home/.ivy2/cache/com.newrelic.agent.java/newrelic-agent/jars/newrelic-agent-3.1.1.jar - When doing cat on my target on the heroku bash however, I do see that the JAR path is correct. Something really fishy is going on here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem is due to a regression in the Scala buildpack. Until it's fixed, you can set your app to use a previous version (working version) of the buildpack by running the following command:

```
heroku config:set BUILDPACK_URL=https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-scala.git#v31
```

Comment: For others: After that a clean push to heroku helps. Did not fix after setting the BUILDPACK and restarting. Set SBT_CLEAN=true and pushed the project, that worked.

Comment: In fairness, i also create the regression so I'm only breaking even! A new version with a fix has been release. You can use it by running `heroku config:unset BUILDPACK_URL`

Comment: Well still, your info helped me out :)

Comment: I stay with the v31 version for now. Better to stay on a save version than having this risk. Thanks for the buildpack however! Using Scala/Akka on Heroku is great.